# New data suriving config changes in activity

Tags: android, kotlin

Lets say, I have an activity that does a network query, recieves data and does something with that data, how fo I perserve that data on config changes not using livemodel, persistant presenters, DB or shared preferences. One variant is actually a new frgment with a bundle, after config changes the activity will restore the fragment with the data, any more sugestions?

following the answer bellow, might be usefull, dont use key and bundle, because bundle lso holds a key. Here's how u can do this in Kotlin

```
object DataHolder {

private val data = HashMap<String, Any>()

fun setData(key: String, data: Any) {
    this.data[key] = data
}

fun getData(key: String): Any? {
    return data[key]
}

fun removeData(key: String) {
    data.remove(key)
}
```

}

Comment: You can use static variable yet be careful using it otherwise you will introduce a leak in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how long you want to preserve the data. If you want it to just be persistent for the current app session, you could use a singleton. Here's an example using a `Bundle`, but you could use any object that holds the data you care about. Here's an example with a map to let you set different persistent data entries with unique String keys.

```
public class MyDataHolder  {

    private static MyDataHolder instance = new MyDataHolder();

    private final HashMap<String,Bundle> data = new HashMap<>();

    private MyDataHolder() {};

    public static MyDataHolder getInstance() {
       return instance;
    }

    public void setData(String key, Bundle data) {
        this.data.put(key,data)
    }

    public Bundle getData(String key) {
        return data.getOrDefault(key, null);
    }
}
```

then in your activity, to save some data

```
MyDataHolder holder = MyDataHolder.getInstance();
holder.setData("ActivityB",data);
```

and to get data (for example, in `onCreate`)

```
MyDataHolder holder = MyDataHolder.getInstance();
Bundle data = holder.getData("ActivityB");
if( data != null ) {
    // use saved config
}
else {
    // use default config
}
```

If you need it to persist beyond the current app session or persist even if the app is killed, you'll need to save it to a local file or network location. That can be either a built-in method (DB, SharedPreferences) but you don't want to use those, so you'd have to write your own method to read and write the data.

Comment: That will do the trick.
In kotlin we can use object without attaching the singleton to the app